# 'float' and 'clear' are acting weird when 'body{padding:0;}' . Why?

Tags: css, css-float, margins

First of all, the html markup,

```
<p>Bananas For BreakFast</p>

<h1>What the what!?</h1>
```

...and the css,

```
body, p, h1, h2, h3, h4{
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

body{
  padding: 30px;
}


/*remove the comment to trigger the effect

body{
  padding: 0;
}

*/


p{
  float: left;
  background-color: red; /*just to aid visualization*/
}

h1{
  clear: both;     
  margin-top: 200px;
  background-color: grey; /*just to aid visualization*/
}
```

You can see it in action at the tinkerbin page below.

http://tinkerbin.com/FJcLuxBr

So, what's my problem?

Simple: while there's padding on the body element the margin-top on the cleared element applies. When 'padding:0;' the 'margin-top' on the same cleared element ceases to work.

Why?

Cleared elements don't participate in margin collapses with elements above it, so this can't be the margin-top collapsing with the body's margin. And even if it were, then the margin should be applied on the body element, pushing the whole thing down - and that's not case.

Comment: so what you want to do? apply padding to body alone and have the margin-top applied to h1 elements only?

Comment: No. This is just some weird behavior I came across, and was wondering about the explanation for it. I'm not trying to achieve a layout - I'm just trying to understand the behavior.

Comment: body { float: left } ha - not sure what other negative effects that might have on everything, but it seems to correct the issue.

Comment: And here I thought I was the only person in the world to use the expression "What the what!?" :)

Comment: I'm curious to know two things: 1) why was this question downvoted at least twice? 2) @Aaron Brewer: Why do you think floated elements are not block elements? What are they, then?

Answer (score 0):

> Cleared elements don't participate in margin collapses with elements above it, so this can't be the margin-top collapsing with the body's margin.

Why not? See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins. I can't find anything there that excudes cleared elements. Note that the element must not be separated from its parent by another cleared element, nor by any borders/paddings.

> And even if it were, then the margin should be applied on the body element, pushing the whole thing down - and that's not case.

No. Again, see the specs:

> If the element's margins are collapsed with its parent's top margin, the top border edge of the box is defined to be the same as the parent's.

Comment: I've figured it out. And what I meant by "cleared elements don't participate in margin collapses(..)" I meant elements that actually introduce 'clearance' - see the specs or wait for my answer( I'll post it when I have some time). But yes, I guess I explained myself badly.

Comment: ... but let me just clarify the 'clearance' thing real quick. It may give you a hint on the answer. If the 'element' with "clear: both, left or right" is already below the bottom edge of the floated element before it, then it doesn't introduce 'clearance', as specified by the specs -  in this case, margin applies, and so does margin collapsing. Otherwise, this is, when clearance is introduced, margin-top doesn't apply and so doesn't the collapsing. Anyway, I'll     give a proper, well structured answer, using the case above as the example, as soon as I have a little time for it.

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo: I think you pretty much grasped it. I don't have to write an answer anymore :)

Answer (score -1):

adding a `clear` div in between makes it work..

http://tinkerbin.com/Ayc4qk3R